# C# Call form from another form

Tags: c#, forms, connect, show-hide, disconnect

**login form** with **"connect"** button in it.
**main form** with a **"disconnect"** button.

Every time i click **"connect"** in the login form i want to **go to the main form**.
Every time i click **"disconnect"** i want to **go back to the login form**.

Here are the codes for the buttons:

```
 private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 
        this.Hide();
        ShowMessage("Successfully connected.");               
        Form MainForm = new MainForm();
        MainForm.Show();                

    }


    private void buttonDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        this.AddOwnedForm(LoginForm);
        LoginForm.Show();
        LoginForm.BringToFront();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Notice the first line in my code:

```
this.Hide();
```

If I **delete** this line, the forms work as i want. However the login form does not hide.

If I **dont delete** this line, 
I click **connect**          --->  the **login form** hides and the **main form** shows up.
Then, I click **disconnect** ---> the **login form** remains hidden. 
Meaning i end up with no forms on my screen to control my application, despite my attempt to make it visible.

```
Login.Show();
Login.BringToFront();
```

*Any help appreciated... wasted almost a full day trying to figure it out.*

Comment: Have you eve worked with MDI forms?

Comment: I have not, im trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
private void buttonDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
    LoginForm frmLogin= (LoginForm)Application.OpenForms["LoginForm"];
    if (frmLogin != null)
    {
        //frmLogin.Visible = true; Uncomment this line if form still not get visible.
        frmLogin.Show();
    }
    else
    {
         frmLogin = new LoginForm();
         frmLogin.Show();
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

and your connect code should be like this

```
private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                 
    this.Hide();
    ShowMessage("Successfully connected.");               
    MainForm frmMain = new MainForm();
    frmMain.Show();                
}
```

Comment: Can i ask what does LoginForm frm = (LoginForm)Application.OpenForms["LoginForm"];   this mean ?

Comment: Error 2 A local variable named 'frmLogin' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'login', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: First time i run it it works well, second time i run it it does NOT hide, every time i run it it creates a new login form... :/, i want to be able to spam connect/disconnect withough creating new windows (forms)

Comment: What is the name of your LoginForm? Can you show your full code of MainForm on http://www.pastie.org?

Comment: this code was edited because i tried a solution in the comments and didnt work, i m so tired right now i cant even think...

Comment: http://pastie.org/9547610#21  this is your code ,  problem with this one is that everytime i click disconect it creates a new login form, when this.Hide() is uncommented , it "seems" like it works , but it just makes new forms every single time i click disconect and they stay hidden , http://pastie.org/9547634#21  this is my code, if i remove the line this.Hide() , it works EXACTLY as i want , BUT i doesnt hide the login form ! , if i comment it and i click login , then disconect, ALL forms become HIDDEN and i cant do anything :/ this is driving me crazy

Comment: welp... u sir are a god :) it fking works....... thank you so much mate... u are awesome

Comment: im gonna ask a general question that i have been trying to find the answer lately and i couldnt.. in my code u saw i had 2 classes , 'Login' and 'FormMySqlQueries' , if i want to add the same funcion 'Function1' to those classes , do i have to copy and paste the code to both of them? isnt there any other , more professional way of doing it ?

Comment: If the function is doing same process and it doesnt use any ui control of the form then you can create another class and make your method as static. Now, you can call that method from both form like `NewClass.MyFunction(param);`

Comment: i understand what you said , thats very useful, is there anyway to do this with UI control, if for example the form1 has a button1 and the form1 also has a button1 ?

Comment: unfortunatly it says "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here" , oh i saw your answer in the chat room, i understand what you mean , thanks so much :) i guess making separate functions is good yeah.

Comment: Accessing the UI from outiside the form is not a good idea. it is better to make function separate. BTW, it is not possible to make common function that can access the UI of more than one form.

Answer (score 0):

In the login form, subscribe to the `MainForm.FormClosed` event:

```
this.Hide();
ShowMessage("Successfully connected.");
Form MainForm = new MainForm();
MainForm.FormClosed += (s, args) => this.Show();
MainForm.Show();
```

Comment: i will try it , thank you. even though i dont know what that does.

Comment: @user3716252 It causes `MainForm` to invoke the specified delegate when it closes. If the syntax is confusing, the delegate is called a lambda expression. You can read about them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: thank you a lot, when i have a clear head i will check it with details.

Comment: @user3716252 Have you tried adding that one line to your original code?

Comment: for the last 30mins im trying to reply to 2 comments per minute, i didnt try your solution yet, i absolutly will though

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Class MainForm
{
    LoginForm login_form;
    public MainForm()
    {

    }
    public MainForm(LoginForm log)
    {
        login_form = log;
    }
    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 


    }

    private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 
        this.Hide();
        ShowMessage("Successfully connected.");

        if(login_form == NULL)
        {              
            login_form = new LoginForm(this);
        }
        login_form.Show();                
    }
}




Class LoginForm
{
    MainForm main_form;
    public LoginForm()
    {

    }
    public LoginForm(MainForm man)
    {
        main_form = man;
    }
    private void LoginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 


    }

    private void buttonDisConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                 
        this.Hide();
        ShowMessage("Successfully Disconnected.");               

        if(main_form == NULL)
        {              
            main_form = new MainForm(this);
        }
        main_form.Show();;                
    }
}
```

Comment: should the login form give me " successfully connected" message ?

Comment: Successfully Connected message is displayed when you click Connect button on Main form and it results a login form is appears.

Comment: i got a "main form" where i can disconect and a "login" form where i only connect

Comment: ok. just swap the form names in these two classes, the logic remains the same.

Comment: trying it as we speak

Comment: (main_form == NULL): Error 1 The name 'NULL' does not exist in the current context, i think i got it mixed up with the codes, i have no idea how your code works

Comment: i have just given you the logic. NULL is not the keyword, its null.

Comment: alright im gonna study this, this is too much for me to think , because my app is pretty huge right now , thanks for this i think its correct

Comment: 2nd row from bottom,   main_form = new MainForm(this);   you are saying "this" which means its a LoginForm but you have public LoginForm(MainForm man)  constructor ? how does this work ?

Comment: so what? public is accessible from anywhere.

Comment: i mean it expects mainForm  and you put in this which is  LoginForm, different types ? or am i retarded ?

Comment: see this is the constructor signature, public MainForm(LoginForm log)... it accepts LoginForm.

Comment: Please post a solution or choose best answer, when found your solution.